# problem in program for schrodinger equation (1D) using RK4 method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

i tried to write a program for 1D SE using rk4. i did it for v=0, for which the equation was,
$\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=-2(E-V(x))\psi$ with $\frac{\hbar^2}{m}=1$.
However, if i used to calculate $v(x)$ using subroutine and use it to calculate the new results, i failed mysteriously. Even looking for its solution, i could not find it. The program which i wrote is given below. Please help me with a way out!

Thanks in anticipation.

! Schrödinger Equation for particle in one dimensional box of length 10 units.

```
    implicit none
    real,parameter::xi=-5,xn=5,yi=0,zi=1,pi=3.141,step=1000
    double precision p,ma
    real x,y,z,x0,y0,z0,y2,d,E,v,v0
    real h,l1,l2,l3,l4,g
    real hh,k1,k2,k3,k4,f,A,B
    integer i,n,m,l
    ! i took mass=1 and hbar=1 for convenience
    v(x)=x**2/2
    f(x,y,z)=z
    g(x,y,z)=-2*(E-v0)*y
    x0=xi
    y0=yi
    z0=zi
    h= (xn-xi)/step
    !write(*,*) h
    n=(xn-xi)/h
    m=n+1
    print*,"Give Energy level n"
    read(*,*) l
    do i=1,n
    d=(xn-xi)
    call potential(i,x0,xi,xn,v0)
    call energy(l,pi,d,E)
    !E=(l**2)*(pi**2)/(2.0*(d**2))
    hh=(h/2)
    k1=f(x0,y0,z0)
    l1=g(x0,y0,z0)
    k2=f(x0+hh,y0+k1*hh,z0+l1*hh)
    l2=g(x0+hh,y0+k1*hh,z0+l1*hh)
    k3=f(x0+hh,y0+k2*hh,z0+l2*hh)
    l3=g(x0+hh,y0+k2*hh,z0+l2*hh)
    k4=f(x0+h,y0+k3*h,z0+l3*h)
    l4=g(x0+h,y0+k3*h,z0+l3*h)
    A=k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4
    B=l1+2*(l2+l3)+l4
    y=y0+(h/6)*A
    z=z0+(h/6)*B
    !write(*,*) x0,y0
    open(unit=10,file="lse.dat")
    write(10,*) x0,y+E
    open(unit=11,file="ene.dat")
    write(11,*) x0,E
    open(unit=12,file="step.dat")
    write(12,*) x0,v0
    x0=x0+h
    y0=y
    z0=z
    y2=(y0)*(y0)
    open(unit=13,file="pde.dat")
    write(13,*) x0,y2+E
    enddo
    print*,"VALUE OF ENERGY IS"
    write(*,*) E,v(x)-E
    stop
    end
```

!-----------------------------------------------------

```
    subroutine energy(l,pi,d,E)
    real,intent(in):: pi,d
    integer,intent(in):: l
    real,intent(out)::E
    real :: p,ma
    p=1.0d0
    ma=1.0d0
    E=(l*l)*(pi**2)*(p**2)/(2.0d0*ma*(d*d))
    return
    end subroutine energy
```

!--------------------------------------------------------

```
    subroutine potential(i,x0,xi,xn,v0)
    real,intent(in)::x0,xi,xn
    integer,intent(in)::i
    real,intent(out)::v0
    v(x0)=x0**2/2.0d0
    v0=v(x0)
    return
    end subroutine potential
```

!--------------------------------------------------------
one of the plots obtained for first energy level is;

[green line shows potential, violet one is for wave function and blue one for energy of first energy level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llz05.jpg)

Comment: What are the initial or boundary conditions? And have you tried using a standard solver like Matlab/Ocataves's ode45 to test your work?

Comment: boundry conditions are yi=0, zi=1..................y are wavefunctions. it is a fortran program (77)

Comment: no i dont understand matlab... it looks for me messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot solve this equation using RK4 the way you're using it. Here's a couple of reasons

1. You do not know the value of $E$ beforehand, $E$ is formally calculated as an eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian. Actually you can plot $E$ and see for yourself that is not constant
2. Boundary conditions are not properly handled with this method, and this is a big deal for solving Schrodinger's equation

What you need to do is solve the eigenvalue problem

$$
H\psi = E\psi
$$

for

$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \hat{V}(x)
$$

which can be discretized using [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). The result is a linear system than can be solved using many [eigenvalue algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm).

Follow [this](http://physics.bu.edu/~py502/lectures4/schrod.pdf) link for details about the implementation